# BIRT reports not show Unicode characters on Linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, birt

I have deployed BIRT3.7.1 reports on a Redhat Linux production server in a birt-viewer directory and the problem is that not all unicode characters are displayed, and after failure the left report is blank. Reports are developed on a windows xp x64 machine and I have copied all windows fonts to the linux machine but still the same problem.
Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I try to generate pdf, htm is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, that we used sans-serif font on the reports. Fixed it changing font to Arial.