# Missing Chinese characters on Linux running BIRT report

Tags: java, unicode, fonts, birt

I am trying to print 针叶樱桃提取物 on a PDF report from BIRT. Instead it displays 针桃提取物, so missing 叶樱 in the PDF. This is a font issue, similar to [this person's problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744362/birt-reports-not-show-unicode-characters-on-linux) However, we are already using a sans-serif font. That person's solution was some difference in the font.

Does anyone know the proper fonts to be using in a Linux context for this kind of thing?

Comment: Easiest would be try out the font(s). Linux life-CD, copy the text (from here for instance), and experiment with local fonts in an editor. Or use a working font from another platform.

Comment: In the question you linked as similar issue, the solution was to change fonts from sans-serif to Arial. So did it work for you ? sans-serif doesn't seem to have those characters.

Comment: @user568109, no it did not. We were already using Arial.

Comment: apparently you should use a Chinese font. Did you try?

Comment: Maybe the content of the pdf is correct, but your pdf viewer is missing some Chinese font. Can you upload the pdf somewhere so I can check it?

Comment: @Alan, the PDF is confidential, I could reproduce it without it, I suppose. I'll work on that, but it isn't a single PDF viewer, multiple ones have the problem. You can copy and paste the text out into a web browser and all the characters are there, so they are in the PDF, just not rendered because they are missing in the font.

Comment: Did you try editing fontsConfig.xml to specify the exact font-family to use for catalog="Chinese"?

Comment: I face the same issue (with different language), when i already have font as embedded subset and will trying to add new characters in document, without adding new glyphs in subset.

Answer (score 7):

**Problem**

This font problem isn't due to a serif / sans serif font, per se, but rather due to a font that doesn't cover the characters in the text.  The unrendered characters refer to 'leaf of cherryblossom' and are part of Han script ([CJK unified ideographs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs)):

```
Glyph   Unicode code point   Represents                                              Code Block                 

叶      U+53F6               to harmonize, to rhyme; to unite; (borrowed for) leaf   CJK Unified (plane 5 stroke 5)
樱      U+6A31               cherry/cherryblossom                                    CJK Unified (plane 6 stroke 15)
```

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/53f6/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/6a31/index.htm
http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/u+53f6/properties
http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/u+6A31/properties

The unicode code points are "universal virtual representation" of the characters - they are not included in your file nor rendered on your screen.

The process goes:

```
Author's Head/        Virtual Space           Bytes In
Generating Tool --->  (Incl. Strings    --->  File        ---->  Screen/Printer
                       In Tool Memory)

Desired               Unicode             Character Encoded    Symbol Rendered Via 
Language Symbol       Code Point          Via Nominated        Nominated Font In  
                                          File Encoding        File
```

On Microsoft, Arial masks the need for matching font to text, because [Arial Unicode MS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS) font is actually a large extension beyond [Arial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial) font - it includes most Microsoft code pages, including [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_936), which contains both of these characters.

Modern Linux installations should have supporting fonts.  If your's doesn't, then certainly it was installed without Chinese language features.  An example of using the [Ubuntu admin language support features](http://www.pinyinjoe.com/linux/ubuntu-10-chinese-setup.htm) to fix this.  Type the following to discover matching fonts:

```
xlsfonts | grep gb
xlsfonts | grep big5
xlsfonts | grep han
xlsfonts | grep ming
xlsfonts | grep song
xlsfonts | grep kai
```

1. **Download Chinese/Asian Fonts for Linux**

   - **From Adobe:**

     http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?platform=windows&product=10 (go to Add-Ons)
     http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4883
     http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?platform=windows&product=10

     **Advantage:** If you generate a PDF using these fonts, then when user attempts to read PDF with  adobe reader without having the fonts installed, they are automatically notified and prompted to download the fonts.  Gives compatablity on non-Linux clients.

     Adobe hosts a blog on [CJK Fonts, Character Sets and Encoding](https://blogs.adobe.com/CCJKType/)
   - **Non-Adobe:**

     Fonts supporting [CJK on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts).

     On Linux, the following fonts support these two characters:

     - GNU Unifont
     - Ming Typeface
     - AR PL UMing (or AR PL ShanHeiSun Uni, AR PL 上海宋)
     - ttf-arphic-uming
     - WenQuanYi Bitmap Song (文泉驿点阵宋体) wqy-bitmapfont
     - Sans Serif
     - WenQuanYi Zen Hei (文泉驿正黑)    wqy-zenhei
     - WenQuanYi Micro Hei (文泉驿微米黑)  wqy-microhei
     - Regular Typeface
     - AR PL UKai (AR PL 中楷)   ttf-arphic-ukai

     See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#.28Mainly.29_Chinese

     If you download yourself, you'll need admin permission to copy fonts to the appropriate linux directory (as defined in `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`, E.g. `/var/font/truetype, /usr/share/fonts, /usr/local/share/fonts,` and `/home/<username>/.fonts`).  [Directions here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/Chinese-HOWTO.pdf) and also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Multilingual_support_%28East_Asian%29).

     **Disadvantage:** You'll need to manually distribute these fonts to clients.  Risk of incompatability on non-Linux clients.
2. **Configure Font Path in Birt**

   **After changing fontsConfig.xml in this step and the next, BIRT needs to be restarted for the changes to have effect.**

   Set the `font-paths` element fontsConfig.xml;

   ```
   <font-paths>
        ---------------
        ---------------
        ---------------
         <path path="/var/font/truetype" />
   </font-paths>
   ```

   Note also, the block element allows you to specify that a font only applies to characters in a certain range, allowing dynamic switching of font for different text (useful for multi-lingual/multi-symbol texts:

   ```
   <block name="Thai" start="e00" end="e7f" index="27" font-family="Font-Family"/>
   ```
3. **Configure Font Encoding(s) in Birt:**

   Also in `fontConfig.xml`, within the `font-encodings` element, ensure your font has an appropriate character encoding that covers your characters.  For example, select one of the following:

   ```
   <font-encodings>
       <encoding font-family="STSong-Light" encoding="UniGB-UCS2-H" />
       <encoding font-family="STSongStd-Light" encoding="UniGB-UCS2-H" />
       <encoding font-family="MHei-Medium" encoding="UniCNS-UCS2-H" />
       <encoding font-family="MSung-Light" encoding="UniCNS-UCS2-H" />
       <encoding font-family="MSungStd-Light" encoding="UniCNS-UCS2-H" />
   </font-encodings>
   ```

   **Note:** any True Type Fonts included will be embedded within the PDF, significantly affecting its size, but also ensuring all clients can correctly read the doc.

   These are Adobe encodings that cover much/all of the broader GB10380 character set as opposed to the older GB2312 set (or EUC-CN), which would be too narrow for you.  The above examples are from BIRT Forum, but a small warning that Adobe is has deprecated UCS2 - it's possible you can replace "UCS2" in strings with "UTF16".

   The reason for using Adobe encodings: Adobe's considered the standard for encoding of broad CJK characters across platforms.  Historically few systems have directly supported the GB10380 character set.  **Also, Adobe encodings and fonts are supported by many printers - an important factor.**  Default Linux charsets/encodings may not support your needs, but you could try referring to the available Linux encodings:

   - available charsets (encodings):   `locale -c`    or   `charsets`
                                     (or Gnome version of the character map program)
   - available Linux locales:          `locale -a`
   - current Linux locale:             `locale`
   - current default charset:          `locale charset`

Comment: How can the font not cover 叶?? This is such a common character.

Comment: It's not part of the historical core chinese character set GB2312.  So has historically been less common than you might think.  Maybe you're on windows or have configured your Linux O/S for Chinese?

Answer (score 0):

On debian I installed a truckload of Chinese and other Asian fonts to make sure this wouldn't happen (again) to me as I generate thousands of PDFs in various character sets.

These are the fonts I installed:

ttf-arphic-bkai00mp ttf-arphic-bsmi00lp ttf-arphic-gbsn00lp ttf-arphic-gbsn00lp ttf-arphic-gkai00mp ttf-arphic-ukai ttf-arphic-uming ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-baekmuk

I'd recommend you to install/deinstall them one by one to see which one you need. For reference on a really good Debian article: [all Chinese fonts in Debian](http://xjqian.wordpress.com/2007/11/13/chinese-fonts-in-debian/)